# JAVA HttpClient with php and Json parsing (not forAndroid)

Tags: java, php, mysql, json

A few days ago, I figured out how to connect Android with a database using the `HttpClient` class and then how to parse the php request result into a Json object.

Now, I would like to do the same thing but for a JAVA EE application matter. The problem is, I started coding JAVA with Android so I don't really know if I can do the same way in a "classic" JAVA application. If someone can help me out with this it would be really cool :)

Basically I'm looking for a way to connect to a mySql server using `HttpClient`, php files (req results encoded in Json), and a Json parser (just like in Android) for a JAVA application purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do this!

You need a few things server-side:

- MySQL database
- PHP code that accesses the database, and writes out JSON

And a few things client-side:

- Java JSON parser (I've used Google GSON but there are others)
- Java library for http requests -- sounds like you already have this under control

---

Let me just emphasize the need for **security**, especially making sure that the PHP code doesn't leave your database vulnerable to attack.

Comment: Ok thank you very much matt :) It sounds like it's possible after all and that's all I wanted to know. If you've got some link to help me starting doing the thing it would be cool though ;) as I have to present a prototype of the procedure very soon (professional reason)